# Cannot log in (nothing happens after entering password) after pressing a key combination at restart

Tags: login, plasma

The plasma desktop can no longer be started. What could be the reason?

Immediately after a restart command (via GUI) I pressed a key combination: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + another key, I think <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>. I'm not sure about the third button.

The next time I booted up, the Kubuntu 16 login screen appeared as usual. After the correct password has been entered, nothing happens at all.

Comment: English please Sir

Comment: Your question still unclear what you're asking. please edit your question with that output Sir?

Comment: what point is unclear, please?

Comment: GUI had needs python2.7 for handle User Interface, " After the correct password has been entered, nothing happens at all." i'm not understand what your mean? Do you have that screenshoot sir?

Comment: there is no direct relation with python.      there were ubuntu 16 with kde neon plasma. thats the gui. wrong passphrase => "access denied"  correct passphrase => nothing happens. no screenshots possible. how should i make it when not logged in? how save it when not logged in?

Comment: Thank you for improving my question. But: i can log in on CLI an d on Gnome. I just can't login to the plasma desktop. That's why I said that the gui was unreachable.

Comment: Sorry i don't get it Sir, have you installed kubuntu-desktop Sir?.

Comment: yes, sir, kubuntu was the original installation. from stick with its kubuntu-desktop and all ...

Answer (score 0):

When you pressed a key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>(F1, 1, 2, F2)</kbd>. It's only show nothing.

You just needs type,

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for Show Desktop KDE.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for show Desktop Settings.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for Open the Window Operations Menu.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> for show System Activity.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for show Run Command Interface.

See more for another Description a key combination of KDE Desktop please see [this](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/kbd.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i doesn't work. i'm running a gnome desktop.  installed KDE with its default desktop a everything default. after pressing a key combination while logging out the session, i was unable to log into plasma desktop. login to terminal was possible. so i installed gnome. but i'd like to have plasma.

Comment: what the output said if you call `sudo tail -f auth.log` sir?

Comment: did you try remove `.cache` folder and restart again like this [topic forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=125034) sir?.